# Any alternative solution for QMessagebox for IOS development (QWidget application only)?

Tags: ios, qt, qt5

I am using Qt 5.3 and trying to develop application for IOS.

Problem is, QWidget application in a iPhone Retina simulator:

1. QMessage becomes full-screen.
2. In Application output panel I see: This plugin does not support
   propagateSizeHints().

So looking for alternative solution for QMessageBox. I don't want to learn QML yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do an overlay on top of your widget you can make something similar to the iOS popups.

Basically you create another widget, and you parent it to the widget you want it to be drawn on top of.

Here are some helpful flags and lines of code to put in your overlay constructor:

```
setPalette(Qt::transparent);
// if you have buttons on this overlay you probably don't want this one
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
dse->setBlurRadius(20);
this->setGraphicsEffect(dse);
```

Then be sure to command a resize of your overlay when the parent widget resizes:

```
void ParentWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    overlay->resize(event->size());
    event->accept();
}
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Widget_Overlay

UPDATE: Awesome example

[image: screenshot of overlay messagebox]

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.resize(300,600);

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "overlaydialogbox.h"
#include <QResizeEvent>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

private:
    OverlayDialogBox * m_overlay;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_overlay = new OverlayDialogBox(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { }

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    m_overlay->resize(event->size());
    event->accept();
}
```

overlaydialogbox.h

```
#ifndef OVERLAYDIALOGBOX_H
#define OVERLAYDIALOGBOX_H

#include <QWidget>

class OverlayDialogBox : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OverlayDialogBox(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void accepted();
    void rejected();
    void finished(int);
public slots:
};

#endif // OVERLAYDIALOGBOX_H
```

overlaydialogbox.cpp

```
#include "overlaydialogbox.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QGraphicsEffect>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QIcon>

OverlayDialogBox::OverlayDialogBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    // if you have buttons on this overlay you probably don't want this one
//    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);

    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    dse->setBlurRadius(20);
    this->setGraphicsEffect(dse);

    QGridLayout * grid = new QGridLayout();
    this->setLayout(grid);

    QMessageBox * msg = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Warning,"Testing","This is a test QMessageBox.");
    QObject::connect(msg, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SIGNAL(accepted()));
    QObject::connect(msg, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SIGNAL(finished(int)));
    QObject::connect(msg, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SIGNAL(rejected()));
    QObject::connect(msg, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(close()));

    msg->setPalette(Qt::white);

    grid->addWidget(msg);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Really awesome.