# QT window within window?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm setting up a small code editor using QT and following [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html). However, i'm curious on how to create windows within windows or widgets within widgets. I'm trying to achieve something similar to these:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn8Ut.png

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/Download-Visual-Studio-2013-while-your-f_1431E/image_4eb5427c-1ae7-4464-9c26-2282fe8d06c3.png

Is there an example of overlaying widgets like this?

Comment: Take a look at Qt::Popup window flags. You may pass it to `QWidget` constructor.

Comment: parent/child relations are used to control display also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Any alternative soloution for QMessagebox for IOS development (QWidget application only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393528/any-alternative-soloution-for-qmessagebox-for-ios-development-qwidget-applicati/24394628#24394628)

I gave an example of getting another `QWidget` to be embedded and painted on top of another one.  Let me know if you have any questions about how it was done.

The `PopUp` flag and `Qt::Tool` options are also relevant.

Be sure to check out: the `ToolTip` property of a `QWidget` and the `WhatsThis` property of `QWidget`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#whatsThis-prop

There are also other ways to make borderless, focusless windows that hover and disappear quickly on command.  The `Window Flags` and `Widget Attributes` in Qt are very powerful when you are looking to modify Qt Widgets.

When you parent a Widget to another widget, it will draw itself on top of the other.  Then you just need to resize and position it properly.

Also subclassing existing widgets can give you more options.

[Draw text on scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606122/draw-text-on-scrollbar/22741363#22741363)

Also common `Qt::Tool`s that you will find are `QDockWidget`s.  They are awesome!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Qt Namespace especially Qt::WA_LayoutOnEntireRect and Qt::WA_StyleSheet. Pass it as a widget attrybutes. The second option looks promising but you have to create style sheet for QWidget.

Comment: I checked that, but it does not allow me to draw anywhere on the screen, or change focus.